# Schedule a batch every 30 mins doesnot work

Tags: scheduled-apex, schedulebatch

I have scheduled a bacthed and i am expecting it to work every 30 mins.
but it runs once every 1 hr
Could you please let me know what i might be missing?

```
string timeinterval = '0 30 * * * ?';
System.schedule('BatchAccountUpdate',timeinterval, new ScheduleBatchApex());
```

As per my understanding i might need to write another schedule statement.Am i correct?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are right, you will need two schedule statements to run the scheduled job every 30 minutes.

```
System.schedule('Scheduled Job 1', '0 0 * * * ?', new ScheduledClass());
System.schedule('Scheduled Job 2', '0 30 * * * ?', new ScheduledClass());
```

Or you can schedule the next job from `finish()` method.